# How to convert Scala.js application to CommonJS module?

Tags: commonjs, scala.js

Is there any standard way to use Scala.js application as a libriary in CommonJS environment? And if not, can I patch generated js file for that purpose?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Scala.js 0.6.13 and onward

Put this in your build file:

```
scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule
```

### Scala.js 0.6.5 to 0.6.12

Put this in your build file (explanation see below):

```
scalaJSOutputWrapper := ("var __ScalaJSEnv = { exportsNamespace: exports };", "")
```

### Scala.js 0.5.4 to 0.6.4

You can tell Scala.js where to send the stuff it exports. To make a CommonJS module, simply prepend this:

```
var __ScalaJSEnv = {
   exportsNamespace: exports
};
```

to the `.js` file produced by `fastOptJS`/`fullOptJS`.

### Pre Scala.js 0.5.4

Please upgrade :)

Comment: As of Scala.js 0.6.5, this can be automated with a single line of sbt configuration: `scalaJSOutputWrapper := ("var __ScalaJSEnv = { exportsNamespace: exports };", "")`. It will be include in the `-fastopt.js` and `-opt.js` files.